# Need to change URL of wiki on SharePoint 2007 (MOSS)

Tags: sharepoint, url, sharepoint-2007, wiki

I created a wiki in SharePoint 2007 with the title "Test Wiki," not realizing that I was stuck with that URL (yeah, I know...). I created a bunch of pages on the wiki, and now I want to modify the URL to just "wiki." Changing the title through the web interface does not change the URL. I have SharePoint designer and I read elsewhere that you can rename a list and it will change the URL... but what happens to all the wiki pages? Will the links all break?

Just to be clear (this is my first question here), an example of a current page in my wiki is something like

```
https://moss.mycompanyname.com/supportdesk/test%20wiki/usermanuals.aspx
```

and I want it to be

```
https://moss.mycompanyname.com/supportdesk/wiki/usermanuals.aspx
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give it a try with SharePoint Designer ? If the links break, you can always switch back to 'test wiki' with SPD and try something else. :-)

Comment: Argh.. I can't believe it was that obvious. Thank you so much. For future reference, it does retain the links.